# Tile and longlistselector itemTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I would like to to create an itemtemplate of longlistselector using a tile
is it possible? 
how to do it in xaml?
could someone show me some code to do it?

Comment: What do you mean, "using a Tile"? Using it where? Could you add the XAML you've tried so it's more clear what you want to do?

Comment: is it possible to declare a tile (icon tile for example) in xaml?

Comment: It could just be a `Border` with content, couldn't it?

Comment: no, i want the xaml of tile, it is not juste a border :/

Comment: What do you want in the `tile`? It can be any XAML you want. A `Border` can contain `content` which could be any XAML. There's not a standard. Add some code to your question please to help clarify.

Comment: Why you do not accept answers for the previous questions?

Answer (score 0):

Using a longlistselector is very easy for this tile applications.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TileDataTemplate">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
              Margin="0,0,12,12">
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="6,0,0,6"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<phone:LongListSelector Margin="0,0,-12,0"
                                    SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged"
                                    LayoutMode="Grid"
                                    GridCellSize="150,150"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding DataBindingItems}"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TileDataTemplate}"
                                    />
```

here the most important thing note is the **LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="150,150"** properties.

**Edit:::**
I have added the code for the tile where i would show up a tile with two textblocks showing up some content on top and then title in the end. The way you have to wire up some sample data or dynamic depends on code behind. Ping me if that is needed. And this is really basic stuff. Accept if you get the answer.

Comment: but i am searching the code to set there   <--your code for a tile --> i don't khnow how to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
 // find the tile object for the application tile that using "flip" contains string in it.
        ShellTile oTile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip".ToString()));


        if (oTile != null && oTile.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("flip"))
        {
            FlipTileData oFliptile = new FlipTileData();
            oFliptile.Title = "Hello WP8!!";
            oFliptile.Count = 11;
            oFliptile.BackTitle = "Updated Flip Tile";

            oFliptile.BackContent = "back of tile";
            oFliptile.WideBackContent = "back of the wide tile";

            oFliptile.SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/159x159.png", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.BackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/336x336.png", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("Assets/Tiles/Flip/691x336.png", UriKind.Relative);

            oFliptile.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/A336.png", UriKind.Relative);
            oFliptile.WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/Flip/A691.png", UriKind.Relative);
            oTile.Update(oFliptile);
            MessageBox.Show("Flip Tile Data successfully update.");
        }
        else
        {
            // once it is created flip tile
            Uri tileUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?tile=flip", UriKind.Relative);
            ShellTileData tileData = this.CreateFlipTileData();
            ShellTile.Create(tileUri, tileData, true);
        }
```

Comment: i want to impement in xaml the tile corresponding to this code behind (native tile) @Max

Comment: Tiles have no xaml. Tiles are images + some text overlays. It can be easily done in xaml with two grids, one over another.

Comment: but it hase not the native behavor like flipTile, iconTile or Cycle tile

Comment: Windows phone have no templates for tiles like Windows 8 modern UI. Even the system build them in some manner, you can't get it. Tiles is only images with text overlays for developers.